Find multiple cases per ID in R
I have a table that is supposed to have the same value in hla-b27 for each patient_id but this was not the case. Therefore, I am looking for a function that allows me to list each patient_id in which I have more than one hla-b27 value per patient. I found a somewhat similar case, except it predefines the possible outcomes:
Is there an R function that can find multiple values per group?
This is a dummy version of the data I have:



hla-b27
patient_id




1.3
01


3.4
01


3.4
01


2.6
02


2.6
02


2.6
02


6.3
06


6.3
06


6.3
06



This is what I try to get:



patient_id
multiple_hla_b27




01
1


02
0


06
0



Best,
J
I tried adjusting the code for the similar issue, but wasn't sure how to adjust it

aggregate(hla-b27 ~ patient_id, data = df, FUN = \(x) +(length(unique(x)) > 1))

Or simply dplyr::count(mydata, patient_id, hla_b27)
